# Is it possible to use a NFC tag as password for an Android application?

Tags: android, nfc

If someone knows about `Truecrypt/Veracrypt`, it's possible to define a file as password. I would like to reproduce the same with a NFC tag in Android.

I will soon receive my Oneplus 5 that is compatible with NFC and I would like to use a tag NFC in order to decrypt/open/write a password automatically.

I don't mind that people can see what is inside the TAG. They will need my fingerprint to access to my phone anyway.

Could you tell me if this is possible or not ?